# Bluemix CLI on Linux - websocket: bad handshake

Tags: linux, logging, command-line-interface, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm able to push and execute a Java sample application under a Bluemix account but when running the log command through the CLI prompt I receive an  error message as shown below:

```
 cf logs myapp-myname --recent
Connected, dumping recent logs for app myapp-myname in org myname@xy.red.com / space dev as myname@xy.red.com...

FAILED
websocket: bad handshake
```

My local platform the runs the CLI is Linux, see the currently installed version:

```
cf -version
cf version 6.1.2-6a013ca
```

When accessing the log records through the web console dashboard, all log information is shown correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because you are using an old version of Cloud Foundry CLI. This version is not supported in Bluemix.

Please use the link below to get a more recent version:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

Comment: thanks @Alex da Silva, worked perfectly. Here my install sequence:

Comment: cf -version
cf version 6.1.2-6a013ca

sudo rpm -Uvh /home/myuserid/Downloads/bluemix_cli/cf_cli/cf-cli-installer_6.14.0_x86-64.rpm

cf --version
cf version 6.14.0+2654a47-2015-11-18

cf logs oauth2java --recent
.. log output is OK ..